# htaccess and mod_rewrite using multiple querystrings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I am currently using htaccess to rewrite a single querystring to it's page name using the following and it's working fine...

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
  # but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

My issue is that I am now trying to implement additional querystrings on top of the original. I can successfully access the page as `/property-listing&property=12-Langworthy-Royston-Grove`

However I would like to be able to rewrite the `&property=` to just be a forward slash, so essentially remove the additional querystring parameter, while maintaining the normal rewriting rules if no additional querystring parameters are passed.

Thanks for any help,

Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule before last:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)&property=(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

However note, that this will only work if `&property=` is part of URI (in the example you shown it is), because it is only the URI which is the subject of rewriting rule, not query-string.